# Joomla 2.5 - How to hide featured articles in blog category layout?

Tags: php, joomla2.5

On the Homepage I have an article-slider module which displays the Featured articles from category "A".

On the same page, below the slider I want to display the non-featured articles from category "A", in Blog category layout. The problem is, that in the Joomla settings (menu type: Blog category) I didn't find any option to hide the featured articles.

I didn't find an external component either, so I wanted to do a joomla core hack. I just don't know, which php file should be modified...
I already looked into /templates/*mytemplate*/html/com_content, but those files are for the displaying of articles, not for the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

I use mod_placehere module from Eike for this. It's very useful module and it works with the latest Joomla 2.5